# $2p-2$ as the sum of consecutive prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Progress**:

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p≡1$ (mod 6) then $2p-2$ can be written uniquely (up to the order of addends) as the sum of some consecutive prime numbers.

These are first ten examples:

$$2⋅7-2=12=5+7$$
$$2⋅13-2=24=11+13$$
$$2⋅19-2=36=17+19$$
$$2⋅31-2=60=29+31$$
$$2⋅37-2=72=5+7+11+13+17+19$$
$$2⋅43-2=84=41+43$$
$$2⋅61-2=120=59+61$$
$$2⋅67-2=132=13+17+19+23+29+31$$
$$2⋅73-2=144=71+73$$
$$2⋅79-2=156=17+19+23+29+31+37$$

I don't even have the slightest idea that how and from where to start the proof. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try $p = 97$? @JackD'Aurizio: I think he wants to write $2p-2$ as the sum of $2$ or $6$ *consecutive* primes.

Comment: Yes I did and in this case it's not the sum of two or six consecutive primes but it is the sum of $ten$ consecutive primes. $$5+7+11+13+17+19+23+29+31+37=192=2*97-2$$ So, let's modify the conjecture a bit; let's say: $p$ be a prime such that $p≡1$ (mod 6) then $2p−2$ can be written uniquely (up to the order of addends) as the sum of some consecutive prime numbers. @JimmyK4542

Comment: See whether it works for all the primes up to one million, and then get back to us.

Comment: Actually, at the first place I thought I wouldn't specify the number of primes(addends) but then I thought that two or six will work! But as I'm proved wrong in that particular claim I changed (as you might see in the previous comment) my mind about the specified addends. So, Instead of **Seeing whether it works for all the primes up to one million** I'm challenging you to produce a counter example and prove me wrong again. Thanks. @GerryMyerson

Comment: No, that's not how mathematics works. The onus is on **you** to demonstrate that the question is worth thinking about by showing that the "conjecture" doesn't fall down at the next hurdle. If you are interested in this problem, then you should put in the hard yards.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try the next prime that is $1 \pmod{6}$, i.e. $p = 97$.

We want either $2$ or $6$ consecutive primes which sum to $2 \cdot 97 - 2 = 192$.

Since $89,97,101$ are consecutive primes and $89+97 = 186 < 192 < 198 = 97+101$, we see that we cannot write $192$ as the sum of $2$ consecutive primes.

Since $19,23,29,31,37,41,43$ are consecutive primes and $19+23+29+31+37+41 = 180 < 192 < 204 = 23+29+31+37+41+43$, we see that we cannot write $192$ as the sum of $6$ consecutive primes.

Therefore, $p = 97$ is a counterexample to your conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. Yes $97$ is a counter example as it cannot be written as the sum of _two_ or _six_ consecutive prime numbers, but it can be written as the sum of _ten_ consecutive prime numbers: $$5+7+11+13+17+19+23+29+31+37=192=2*97-2$$

So, the new _conjecture_ is: let $p$ be a prime such that $p≡1$ (mod 6) then $2p−2$ has a unique solution (up to the order of addends) as the sum of two or more consecutive prime numbers. Thanks. @Jimmy

Answer (score 1):

Try $p =  157, 223, 337, 397, 439, \ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

There are many counterexamples to your conjecture. The numbers below cannot be written as the sum of consecutive prime numbers:

$ 157, 223, 337, 397, 439, 487, 499, 631, 673, 709, 739, 751, 757, 769, 787, 907, 967, 997, 1069, 1087, 1117, 1171, 1237, 1249, 1297, 1399, 1423, 1447, 1471, 1543, 1567, 1579, 1657, 1777, 1831, 1861, 1867, 1987, 2011, 2017, 2137, 2179, 2203, 2221, 2251, 2287, 2347, 2371, 2377, 2389, 2437, 2467, 2503, 2617, 2677, 2683, 2707, 2749, 2767, 2833, 2917, 2953, 3019, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3163, 3187, 3217, 3229, 3319, 3433, 3499, 3517, 3571, 3631, 3643, 3691, 3697, 3727, 3739, 3847, 3877, 3889, 3907, 3943, 4027, 4201, 4297, 4363, 4441, 4507, 4561, 4567, 4591, 4597, 4621, 4657, 4813, 4861, 4909, 4951, 4987, 4999, 5059, 5077, 5167, 5179, 5227, 5323, 5431, 5449, 5527, 5557, 5569, 5581, 5623, 5737, 5749, 5779, 5791, 5821, 5839, 5857, 5953, 6037, 6067, 6079, 6121, 6211, 6217, 6247, 6373, 6379, 6397, 6427, 6469, 6481, 6547, 6577, 6607, 6619, 6637, 6673, 6679, 6967, 6997, 7027, 7039, 7057, 7177, 7207, 7297, 7321, 7369, 7411, 7417, 7477, 7537, 7603, 7639, 7669, 7699, 7753, 7867, 7933, 7963, 7993, 8017, 8101, 8167, 8179, 8191, 8209, 8287, 8311, 8317, 8329, 8353, 8419, 8443, 8467, 8563, 8581, 8689, 8707, 8713, 8719, 8737, 8779, 8887, 8893, 8923, 8929, 9103, 9109, 9127, 9133, 9157, 9181, 9187, 9199, 9277, 9391, 9397, 9403, 9511, 9547, 9601, 9613, 9619, 9643, 9649, 9661, 9697, 9733, 9739, 9781, 9787, 9817, 9829, 9871, 9901, 9907, 9973, 10099, 10111, 10159, 10177, 10243, 10321, 10357, 10399, 10453, 10477, 10513, 10567, 10597, 10651, 10663, 10687, 10729, 10753, 10771, 10789, 10837, 10867, 10957, 10993, 11047, \ldots$